# css3 background-size:cover leaving white space on resize

Tags: html, css

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    background:url(../images/imgs/backgrnd.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

The `background-size:cover` works perfectly for the most part and resizing is generally not a problem, but in some cases it leaves a large white strip down at the bottom of the page on some resizes.
The background is a `1920x1080` image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if you solved this problem, but I was tearing my hair out over it for a couple of days and nothing I could Google was helping.  I talked to someone at work on our UI team and it turns out that the body of the web page won't necessarily cover the whole height of the page.  Adding the following to my css file completely solved the problem:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This stretches the content of the body to fit the whole height of the window.  Just including the "body" bit worked for me, but my coworker informed me that it's better to include both because some browsers will act funny with just one.

Comment: Wow this is an old one! Thanks for answering, yea having height:100% and width:100% with background-size:cover; works fine. Interesting note about separating the height and width, I used to do the same, just putting it in body.

Answer (score 5):

Add an `overflow:auto;` to resolve this issue.

**For Instance,**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    background:url(../images/imgs/backgrnd.png) no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2021 and I encountered a similar problem and none of the solutions worked for me.

I managed to figure it out and hope this will help someone.

You will need to set the viewport height and width to 100%. According to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp), The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page. This will eliminate any white spaces by setting the minimum height to that.

```
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can also try using:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

just a suggestion