# white line in bottom of page i can't remove it

Tags: html, css, background-image

[This Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1FSU.jpg)

Code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("../img/background.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid background">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div id="particles-js">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to remove this white line and the scroll I need page full width and height background-image I tried overflow: hidden
but in mobile responsive have problem with login box.

Comment: Can you provide the JS creating the particles as well, or maybe a live demo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just had this problem and found the explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491563/css3-background-sizecover-leaving-white-space-on-resize) to be extremely helpful.

You might want to try using the following code to center your image:

```
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background-image: url("../img/background.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This should remove that white line from the bottom of your page.

Comment: thank you the white line is removed but i still have scroll for nothing

Answer (score 0):

Is late to say it but just put:

```
*{
margin: 0;
}
```