# How can I define a background image to fill the screen and remove edges on the left and right in React with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI with React. In the login page I want to fill the background of the page behind a Paper component with an image. 
I set the `backgroundSize` of the image to `cover` but it still leaves a white edge on the left and the right side of the screen.

This is my Login component:

```
const style = theme => ({
    content: {
        minHeight: '900px',
        backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`,
        backgroundPosition: '50%',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    },
    paper: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        maxWidth: 300,
        margin: 'auto',
    },
});


class Login extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('usertoken') !== null) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
        <div className={classes.content}>
                <br/>
                <Typography variant='h3'>Login</Typography>
                <br/>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                    <Grid container direction='column' justify='space-between' alignItems='center' spacing={1}>
                     //Formik Field inside  
                    </Grid>
                </Paper>
       </div>
)}}
Login.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(style)(Login);
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
<ErrorHandler>
                <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
                    <Router history={history}>
                        <MainHeader/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
                            <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
                        </Switch>
                        <Footer/>
                    </Router>
                </ThemeProvider>
</ErrorHandler>
```

I'm not defining any margin in the app.js.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not worried about aspect ratio

```
let w = window.innerWidth;
let h = window.innerHeight;
...
backgroundSize: w + 'px ' + h + 'px';
```

There are a few ways to deal with it - this might also help https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496015/4241624

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working for me. The edges are still there. And as you said the aspect ratio is now wrong.

Comment: It could also be the scroll bars depending on the browser.  You could also do let `w = window.innerWidth + 10;`

Comment: I set the body margin to 0 like this: `document.body.style.margin = '0';` directly before the `return` statement of my `login` component. This solved it for me. And the aspect ratio is still correct with this solution.